# What is the best way to clean a string for placement in a URL, like the question name on SO?

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, slug

I'm looking to create a URL string like the one SO uses for the links to the questions. I am not looking at rewriting the url (mod_rewrite). I am looking at generating the link on the page.

Example: The question name is:

```
Is it better to use ob_get_contents() or $text .= ‘test’;
```

The URL ends up being:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292068/is-it-better-to-use-obgetcontents-or-text-test
```

The part I'm interested in is:

```
is-it-better-to-use-obgetcontents-or-text-test
```

So basically I'm looking to clean out anything that is not alphanumeric while still keeping the URL readable. I have the following created, but I'm not sure if it's the best way or if it covers all the possibilities:

```
$str = urlencode(
    strtolower(
    str_replace('--', '-', 
    preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9 ]/i', '/[^a-z0-9]/i'), array('', '-'), 
    trim($urlPart)))));
```

So basically:

1. trim
2. replace any non alphanumeric plus the space with nothing
3. then replace everything not alphanumeric with a dash
4. replace -- with -.
5. `strtolower()`
6. `urlencode()` -- probably not needed, but just for good measure.

Comment: **Duplicate** – <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465659/how-can-i-create-a-seo-friendly-dash-delimited-url-from-a-string>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you pointed out already, urlencode() is not needed in this case and neither is trim(). If I understand correctly, step 4 is to avoid multiple dashes in a row, but it will not prevent more than two dashes. On the other hand, dashes connecting two words (like in "large-scale") will be removed by your solution while they seem to be preserved on SO.

I'm not sure that this is really the *best* way to do it, but here's my suggestion:

```
$str = strtolower( 
  preg_replace( array('/[^a-z0-9\- ]/i', '/[ \-]+/'), array('', '-'), 
  $urlPart ) );
```

So:

1. remove any character that is neither space, dash, nor alphanumeric
2. replace any consecutive number of spaces or dashes with a single dash
3. strtolower()

Comment: I would still do the trim() because of possible extra spaces.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right. You wouldn't want a leading or trailing dash. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway.